# How to identify a crystal structure by its x-ray reflection bragg angles?

Tags: solid-state-physics, x-ray-crystallography, braggs-law

How to identify a crystal structure by its x-ray reflection bragg angles?

Suppose we have a crystal sample to examine its crystal structure (e.g. SC, BCC, FCC, etc). What we can get from an X-ray diffraction experiment is the incidence beam wave vector $\vec{k}$, reflected wave vector $\vec{k}'$, and the bragg angles $\theta$.

I know what primitive cell is, what Wigner-Seitz cell is, reciprocal lattice, and how to derive scattering amplitude, and the diffraction condition $\Delta\vec{k}=\vec{G}$, structure form factor. But how can you determine the structure of the sample by x-ray diffraction experiment?

Comment: You compare a model to reality. Apart from some possible degeneracies, if it fits, you got it.

Comment: Each crystal structure has different symmetries, a combination of the Bravais lattice and the unit cell, resulting in the 270 different point groups. These symmetries are then exhibited in the diffraction pattern in a deterministic way through the scattering amplitude and conditions.  It is 'easy' for an experienced x-ray diffraction expert to determine the Bravais lattice symmetry.  Complex unit cells make life harder, but it all follows from symmetry (which Wigner was really good at).

Answer (score 1):

With the x-ray diffraction and the Bragg's equation '2dsint=n^ you can get the inter planer spacing 'd' which can also lead you to get the lattice constant which is a vital property of a crystal structure.